# Database/ERM - What step follows creation of a State Diagram in the creation of the ER Diagram for Database Design?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

**Note**

I realize this question might be specific among different approaches for database design but I am a bit uncertain about the next steps I need to do to go forward, for my specific case.

**I have tried to leave out specifics, but If this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, I will try other means to find out.**

**Here is my Scenario**

I have a project in which I need to create an ER diagram for database design for an Action Item Tracking system which I defined as the primary entity I am representing in my database for an Action Item tracking project (my own proposal) for teams working on various projects in a company.

Per the recommendation of the instructor of a class which this is for, I have been advised to provide a State Diagram, for clarifying problem definition for my primary entity (Action Item) for database design.

**My question is, what is usually generally done next while translating the State Diagram to an ER diagram?**

Answer (score 1):

Usually I begin with a data model before starting on the state model. A state model can be used to verify that the data model is able to support the different states an entity goes through.

For example lets assume that the action item goes through the following states:

- New
- Assigned
- Rejected
- *etc*

and there is an assignment activity that move action item from the 'New' state to the 'Assigned' state.  That process will have data requirements, one of which is almost certain to be the person to whom the action item is to be assigned.

The data model can be checked to ensure that the model contains entities as well as the necessary attributes and relations:

- Person
- Action Item
- some sort of association between Person and Action Item.

Depending on the tool employed you should be able to do this by mapping the following to the data base:

- The state transition arrows in the state transition diagram.
- The input and output arrows in the activity diagram.

Ideally both the activity and state transition diagrams should be mapped to the data model as this will insure that all three are consistently aligned from a data perspective.

I hope this helps (if not feel free to ask a follow up question)